# Mongodb log shows nscanned for each document in collection

Tags: mongodb, logging, indexing

Occasionally, in my mongodb log, I see a line that looks like this:

```
Tue Nov 22 11:51:41 [conn7647] update my_app.users  query: {} nscanned:1 nscanned:2 nscanned:3 nscanned:4 nscanned:5 nscanned:6 ...
```

The line includes the text `nscanned:<n>` for every user in my users collection.  What is this and is it a problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem, per se. But you've issued a multi-update, so you're probably getting the nscanned for each update in the multi-update. If the overall update takes longer than 100ms, it will be synced to the log. Is that what you're seeing? Can you post the entire log entry?